# GPS locating in small cells

Tags: gps

We have a customer who wants to auto locate product in small numbered cells. The cells are roughly 10'x17'. I have always read that consumer GPS is good to roughly 1-2 meters or 3-6 feet. My question is whether this is feasible at all. We can't control where coordinates are read and it concerns me that we could easily be off by a cell or two regularly (the cells being side to side and back to back with no buffer zone.) Does anyone have experience doing this? The first thought is geo-fencing the cells and performing ray tracing to see if the coordinates recorded are inside a geofence. Any thoughts on this approach or alternatives would be appreciated.

We have not tried this yet and it will take a lot of effort to get there. We are trying to determine if the approach is even worthwhile.

Comment: GPS works well outside. If you have cells inside, you do not get much accuracy. But you can have centimeter precise GPS position (e.g. used on some drones and in many construction workplaces). You need a base station nearby, and a gps unit which can do RTK. Possibly dual band. The trick: relative position is more precise, and such devices can measure also phase difference (so not limited to wavelength precision). But if it is in confined place, and indoor, maybe other methods may be better ("laser beacons" instead of satellites)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Operation is outdoors with Zebra handheld computers. I am not sure that fits the model you describe. All references I have found state 1 meter to 2 meter accuracy.

Comment: Check e.g. https://www.u-blox.com/en/technologies/rtk-real-time-kinematic (one of the largest manufacturer of GPS chips), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_kinematic_positioning, sparkfun has also some tutorials (hardware and software), and ardusimple: these last two are also manufactures/assemblers of cheap microcontrollers (using e,g. ublox chips) (and there are a lot of very expensive manufacturers).